# Minecraft, OpenGL, and the dreaded Bad Graphics Card error!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After hearing about minecraft for a while, I figured I'd head over to Minecraft.net and see what all the fuss was about.  After watching a few tutorials, I was hooked on the concept and decided to buy the game.

After paying for the game, I tried to fire up the app using the in browser version.  It worked but it was dreadfully slow.  No prob-- I noticed that there was a downloadable version so I figured I would give it a try. When I launch the game, I get an error about a bad graphics card driver.  After a bit of googling,I learned that this is usually about the need for openGL support.  I've yet to find a driver that fixes the problem but I wonder if i need too.

Is there something that I can do to get this game to work like it does in the browser?  Maybe a passing the exe a couple of parameters? I am quite curious.  Why would the game work in the browser but not from the download?  What's the difference?

Comment: Also, my jre is up-to-date as well as my graphics drivers. This is a WinXP Pro. machine and it is a Sony Vaio that is about 5 years old.

Comment: Consider perhaps that your browser may be using a different version of Java than the JRE you just installed. I had this error after I installed the 64-bit JRE in the hopes of fixing out-of-memory errors. For me the fix turned out to be installing the newest version of my drivers from nvidia -- I had previously installed through windows to no avail. 32-bit Java (old JRE and Java plugin for 32-bit browsers) worked with the drivers windows thought I should use.

Comment: @RLH: please include more information about your hardware so we can diagnose this better

Comment: Just a note, minecraft has a lot of problems with the 64-bit JRE, make sure you're using the 32-bit version

Comment: @BlueRaja-- I am.  This is a 32-bit PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is mainly to do with Minecraft and not your video card or even your system. Im using an old Dell Latitude x300 laptop with integrated Intel card and play the game just fine (v1.5+). So, most of the answers you may find are from non techs so ignore them. It has more to do with JAVA.

What I have done is to download and use MCPatcher as a launcher since you can allocate memory through it under the Options Tab. You dont have to run any Mods to get this to work and speed up your Minecraft.

MCPatcher
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/232701-611-update173-compatible-mcpatcher-hd-fix-210-02/

Try setting the memory to, like say, 128 first then bring it up later if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've not had the time to do any further research but I have found that I can play the game in a browser, using IE without much difficulty.  I do need to close and reopen the game about every 30 minutes, though.  I would assume that's because of a memory leak, or something of that nature. :/

Answer (score 2):

Dependant on your hardware and your current browser, there could be loads of problems.

**First:** Check to see if your browser is compatible with the entire package. Try Firefox 3.5 or higher due to the fact is has good compatibility.

**Second:** If that doesn't change anything, you can go here: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/10-support/ to ask about if anyone else has had the same issue.

**Third:** If all else fails, it's time to upgrade/change or give up. Sorry.

Comment: Appologies for not responding.  I've been exceptionally busy the past two days and, as you can imagine, gaming comes after work. :(